# Is it bad to drive a vehicle if power steering is defunct?

Tags: power-steering

My truck's power steering pump is broken (leaking) so I had to drain the fluid.  I was able to drive it around the parking lot, with considerable difficulty steering.  I need to get the truck home, which is 25 mi away.  Aside from the difficult steering, are there any other consequences to driving without power steering?

Comment: Do you mean, beside any consequences of having an accident on the drive home caused by the difficult steering?

Comment: i meant, how likely i am to have an accident due to the impaired steering ?  i've never done it

Comment: How _likely_ are you to have an accident with impaired steering? I don't think anyone can answer that for you, but I'd suggest _more_ likely than without impaired steering which you don't have 'considerable difficulty' using. Driving a vehicle you can't properly control and putting lives at risk because you don't want to pay for towing is grossly negligent/irresponsible, please don't do it.

Comment: It's only hard to steer at low speeds.

Comment: lol so yeah just go faster cuz thats always a good answer

Comment: There is hardly any additional danger, you learn to drive without power steering pretty quickly. The 'trick' is to not turn the wheel when the car isn't moving. In a perfect world, you wouldn't turn the wheel when the car isn't moving in a PS equipped car either, as it wears your tires unnecessarily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this question is NO.  It is not bad.  It's just harder to steer.  But that's how people used to drive for many decades before the advent of power steering.  Do, however, make sure that your power steering pump is mounted properly onto the engine block and the serpentine belt because the belt has to have all the pulleys mounted on and tight.

Answer (score 7):

You can damage power steering pump when driving without having fluid in it, if it´s leaking just check it every few miles and you are ok, when there is fluid, it has to work, it´s just leaking right?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the power steering pump has fluid in it.  If it runs dry it can cause your pulley to seize and your belt to break.

Answer (score 1):

No. It literally just makes it harder to steer. When the car is in motion, steering isn't too hard, just gotta put a little more strength. Parked or moving below 10 mph, it's a pain in the ass to steer, depending what car it is. It's not going to damage the car, the pulley will be fine. I have a 95 GT without PS and it's extremely difficult to drive (only because of the weight) but it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The pump runs dry and will burn up if still turning.

The belt then tries to seize and will also burn up.

Get about 2 qts of fluid and keep refilling it..$6 for fluid is way better than $200 for parts. Safety aspect also..huge consequences.